# android - Как заставлять ListView показать весь айтем при клике на него?

Tags: android, listview

Есть список, при нажатии на айтем, блокируется прокрутка и нажатия через `setEnabled(false);`. Когда пользователь нажимает на айтем, торчащий на какую-то часть, нужно делать скролл в сторону этого айтема так, чтобы после щелчка он был виден полностью. Как такое реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Узнать позицию элемента в списке и вызвать для ListView

```
smoothScrollToPosition(int position)
```

Comment: вау :) Огромное спасибо, класс 